# How to use a dependency from nexus and pass a revision

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

On our Nexus server we have a library with version 1.0 and 2.0. I build my main Project with Gradle.

Actually I have a dependency entry in my gradle file to the library from nexus that use lib version 1.0. Everything is fine.

But now I need a Version 2.0 of our library. The Problem is that the POM File of Lib 2.0 on nexus, does not have a standard version Tag anymore with 2.0 in it. like

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<articaftId>...</articaftId>

<version>2.0</version>
```

Instead their is this line

```
...
<version>${revision}</version> 
...
```

When update the dependency in my Gradle file to 2.0 and try to build my Gradle project with

```
gradle clean assemble
```

The build fails with this Message

```
   > Could not resolve com.company.print.lib:print-lib:2.0
     Required by:
         project :com.company.printservice
      > Could not com.company.print.lib:print-lib:2.0
         > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.company.print.lib:print-lib:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT Errors: bad version: expected='2.0' found='0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

How I can solve this? Do I need to pass the Revision ob gradle build?

Comment: Probably version 2.0 of that library was built incorrectly. They would have needed to replace the `${revision}` during the build.

Comment: Other developers who use maven as build tool in theirs Projects  pass 2.0 throw command line   like mvn clean install -Prevision=2.0.

Comment: If you build a library with Maven that has `${revision}` as version, you need to use the flatten maven plugin to replace the version `${revision}` with a proper version before deployment of the artifact to the repository.